# docker commit requires at least 1 and at most 2 arguments

Tags: docker

I m trying to make a jar file automatically started when an image is run :

```
docker commit --change='CMD ["java", "-jar", "/tmp/demo.jar"]' interesting_jang ghaylensaada/demo:version2
```

But i got this error :

```
"docker commit" requires at least 1 and at most 2 arguments.
```

what's wrong in my command?

Comment: Please include `docker version`. Also consider using a Dockerfile to build reproducible images.

Comment: i m using the latest version : 19.03.5, build 633a0ea

Comment: `docker commit` is almost never a best practice.  You should write this into a Dockerfile (including the default `CMD` you want to run) and commit that to source control.  Then when you have a change to your application code you can just re-run `docker build` to get a new image.

Comment: thank you @DavidMaze , but i m using this command just for testing, i saw it in the online course i m taking, but it does not works for me

Answer (score 8):

Use "" instead of ''
'
Example:
docker container commit -c="CMD ["java","-jar","/tmp/hello-world-rest-api.jar"]" keen_benz hello-world-rest-api:manual3

Comment: Please add some explanation to your answer such that others can learn from it

Answer (score 3):

if you are using windows , use power shell instead of cmd, the same command works for me

```
docker commit --change='CMD ["java", "-jar", "/tmp/demo.jar"]' interesting_jang ghaylensaada/demo:version2
```

Comment: This solution worked for me though not sure what special with powershell, up voted your answer

Answer (score 1):

Try using the backslash \ to escape the double quotes, it should work

```
docker commit --change="CMD [\"java\", \"-jar\", \"/tmp/demo.jar\"]" interesting_jang ghaylensaada/demo:version2
```

Comment: This one didn't work out

Comment: Windows people, please add the backward slash before each double quote. `\"`

Answer (score 0):

Try below one for window system, it should work.

```
docker commit --change="CMD java -jar /tmp/demo-api.jar" exciting_lumiere demo/demo-api:manual2
```